# Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the solution of the given differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1(x)$ & $y_2(x)$ be the solutions of the differential equation $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=R(x)$ on $\lbrack a,b\rbrack$ where $P,Q$ & $R$ are continuous functions on $\lbrack a,b\rbrack$.

Prove that either $y_1=y_2$ or the set $\lbrace x\in\lbrack a,b\rbrack:y_1(x)=y_2(x)\rbrace$ is finite.

I don't know how to approach this problem. I mean we can't use methods of solving differential equations. My intuition tells me that we should use methods of Real Analysis here but I can't figure out how.